# perform findOneAndDelete() method to nested objectId in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

How to perform `findOneAndDelete()` method to nested objectId in mongoose. here is my Schema:

```js
...
var favoriteSchema = new Schema(
  {
    dishes: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Dish',
        unique: true,
      },
    ],
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
...
```

And here is a sample document:

```js
{
    "dishes": [
        {
            ...
            "_id": "5ec7b32a793648289c8ad28c",
            "comments": [],
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5ec7dc88c4495c3ad44f32db",
    "user": {
        "_id": "5ec644d06715633270d0414d",
        "username": "falamiw",
    },
    ...
}
```

And in my `/favorites/:dishId` endpoint I want to query the document using the dishId params and if obtain then delete the document from the collection. But How to use `findOneAndDelete({?:req.params.dishId})` ?

Answer (score 1):

What You want to achieve is called `$pull`

Based on Your schema it’s will be:

```js
await Favourite.findOneAndUpdate(
  {"user": userId}, 
  {$pull: 
    {
      "dishes": req.params.deleteUid
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please. what I understand is first you find the document using userId and then do what(I need to delete) with this document? @num8er

Comment: @falamiw it’s pulling out object from favourites.dishes

Comment: Ok if I use this then what will return in the callback from Favourite.findOneAndUpdate(...)? And how to perform delete operation on this document? @num8er

Comment: @falamiw pulling out object from array is deleting object from array of objects. what You want to delete? dish from dishes collection?

Comment: No, dish from favorite collection @num8er

Comment: @falamiw so it’s $pull operation. google it: mongodb delete from array of objects